# GBA C programming compiler gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, game-boy-advance

I am trying to get started in programming for the GBA in Windows. Could somebody point me to a a good reference where they have been able to follow a complete set of directions?

I want the directions to include the following:

```
1) downloading the compiler needed for gba development
2) downloading the gcc necessary for gba development
```

I have tried a few websites but I always run into the problem of getting some variant of gcc installed. If you have not personally downloaded a gba development kit and compiled code for the gba do not answer this thread with a link to cygwin.

Thanks!

Comment: But Cygwin *is* the easiest way to get a copy of GCC running on Windows. The second easiest one is installing Linux in a virtual machine.

Comment: I would happily install Cygwin if it WORKS with GBA development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the link for all aspiring GBA programmers:

http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/setup.htm

For Windows this will download all the gcc tools and GBA development tools you need automatically. It will also make and set a bunch of environment variables for easy compilation, no extra work required! The only thing you need to do is download a GBA emulator, probably visual boy advance.

devKitPro is practically the only maintained GBA development group. Great Website!